# From scraper_user.items import UserItem ImportError: No module named scraper_user.items

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api, scrapy

I am following this guide for scraping data from instagram: 
http://www.spataru.at/scraping-instagram-scrapy/
but I get this error:

```
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/instagram/instagram$ ls
instagram  scrapy.cfg
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/instagram/instagram$ scrapy crawl instagramspider
2017-03-01 15:30:10-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.4 started (bot: instagram)
2017-03-01 15:30:10-0600 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, MemoryUsage, SpiderState
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 132, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 97, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 139, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 43, in run
    spider = self.crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/command.py", line 34, in crawler
    self._crawler.configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 36, in configure
    self.spiders = spman_cls.from_crawler(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 37, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 33, in from_settings
    return cls(settings.getlist('SPIDER_MODULES'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 23, in __init__
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 65, in walk_modules
    submod = __import__(fullpath, {}, {}, [''])
  File "/home/mona/computer_vision/instagram/instagram/instagram/spiders/spider.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scraper_user.items import UserItem
ImportError: No module named scraper_user.items
```

I followed the complete tutorial so I am not sure what's missing or how to fix this?

Here's the folder structure:

```
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/instagram/instagram$ tree .
.
├── instagram
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   └── spiders
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.pyc
│       ├── spider.py
│       └── spider.pyc
└── scrapy.cfg

2 directories, 11 files
```

here's the spider.py code from the tutorial:

```
  1 import scrapy
  2 import json
  3 from scraper_user.items import UserItem
  4 from scraper_user.items import PostItem
  5 
  6 
  7 class InstagramSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  8 
  9     name = 'instagramspider'
 10     allowed_domains = ['instagram.com']
 11     start_urls = []
 12 
 13     def __init__(self):
 14         self.start_urls = ["https://www.instagram.com/_spataru/?__a=1"]
 15 
 16     def parse(self, response):
 17         #get the json file
 18         json_response = {}
 19         try:
 20             json_response = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
 21         except:
 22             self.logger.info('%s doesnt exist', response.url)
 23             pass
 24         if json_response["user"]["is_private"]:
 25             return;
 26         #check if the username even worked
 27         try:
 28             json_response = json_response["user"]
 29 
 30             item = UserItem()
 31 
 32             #get User Info
 33             item["username"] = json_response["username"]
 34             item["follows_count"] = json_response["follows"]["count"]
 35             item["followed_by_count"] = json_response["followed_by"]["count"]
 36             item["is_verified"] = json_response["is_verified"]
 37             item["biography"] = json_response.get("biography")
 38             item["external_link"] = json_response.get("external_url")
 39             item["full_name"] = json_response.get("full_name")
 40             item["posts_count"] = json_response.get("media").get("count")
 41 
 42             #interate through each post
 43             item["posts"] = []
 44 
 45             json_response = json_response.get("media").get("nodes")
 46             if json_response:
 47                 for post in json_response:
 48                     items_post = PostItem()
 49                     items_post["code"]=post["code"]
 50                     items_post["likes"]=post["likes"]["count"]
 51                     items_post["caption"]=post["caption"]
 52                     items_post["thumbnail"]=post["thumbnail_src"]
 53                     item["posts"].append(dict(items_post))
 54 
 55             return item
 56         except:
 57             self.logger.info("Error during parsing %s", response.url)
```

Here's the items.py code:

```
  1 import scrapy
  2 
  3 class UserItem(scrapy.Item):
  4     username = scrapy.Field()
  5     follows_count = scrapy.Field()
  6     followed_by_count = scrapy.Field()
  7     is_verified = scrapy.Field()
  8     biography = scrapy.Field()
  9     external_link = scrapy.Field()
 10     full_name = scrapy.Field()
 11     posts_count = scrapy.Field()
 12     posts = scrapy.Field()
 13 
 14 
 15 class PostItem(scrapy.Item):
 16     code = scrapy.Field()
 17     likes = scrapy.Field()
 18     thumbnail = scrapy.Field()
 19     caption = scrapy.Field()
 20     hashtags = scrapy.Field()
```

Comment: You can display directory structure by using `tree` command.

Comment: you don't have a `scraper_user` package (folder)

Comment: Judging by your tree it should be `instragram.items` instead of `scrapy_user.items` shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I changed these lines in spider.py:

```
  3 from instagram.items import UserItem
  4 from instagram.items import PostItem
```

And these lines in items.py:

```
  1 import scrapy
  2 from scrapy.item import Item, Field
  3 
  4 class UserItem(Item):
  5     username = Field()
  6     follows_count = Field()
  7     followed_by_count = Field()
  8     is_verified = Field()
  9     biography = Field()
 10     external_link = Field()
 11     full_name = Field()
 12     posts_count = Field()
 13     posts = Field()
 14 
 15 
 16 class PostItem(Item):
 17     code = Field()
 18     likes = Field()
 19     thumbnail = Field()
 20     caption = Field()
 21     hashtags = Field()
~
```

While it doesn't have the previous error, it has this new error which I didn't know how to fix:

```
mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/instagram/instagram$ scrapy crawl instagramspider
2017-03-01 17:24:03-0600 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.14.4 started (bot: instagram)
2017-03-01 17:24:04-0600 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, MemoryUsage, SpiderState
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 4, in <module>
    execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 132, in execute
    _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 97, in _run_print_help
    func(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 139, in _run_command
    cmd.run(args, opts)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/commands/crawl.py", line 43, in run
    spider = self.crawler.spiders.create(spname, **opts.spargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/command.py", line 34, in crawler
    self._crawler.configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 36, in configure
    self.spiders = spman_cls.from_crawler(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 37, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 33, in from_settings
    return cls(settings.getlist('SPIDER_MODULES'))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/spidermanager.py", line 23, in __init__
    for module in walk_modules(name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 65, in walk_modules
    submod = __import__(fullpath, {}, {}, [''])
  File "/home/mona/computer_vision/instagram/instagram/instagram/spiders/spider.py", line 7, in <module>
    class InstagramSpider(scrapy.Spider):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Spider'
```